# Is there any way to start with any other value in ggplot in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am working with cumulative data in bar chart. But I couldn't find any way to change the y value for cumulative value. Almost all examples on the internet are about not cumulative ones. Is there any way to start with a specific value (e.g. 30 instead of 0) on y-axis in the bar chart using ggplot in R?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can set `ylim` inside `coord_cartesian`

```r
library(ggplot2)

df <- data.frame(x = c("A", "B"), y = c(45, 60)) 

ggplot(df, aes(x, y)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  coord_cartesian(ylim = c(30, 70))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-01-29 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Thank you for your replying.  I managed to do that this way.